# What should be a minimal stake for Casino to secure the profit?

Tags: expected-value

Let's assume Casino has a game, where the expected value of an outcome is 60% for Casino.

The casino has 1000 units of money in reserve for this game.
Stakes are always 500 units of money.

Now John comes and wins twice in a row. In this case, the casino lost all reserves.

My question is, what should be a minimal stake set by the casino, to avoid losing reserves? Does there exist a formula for this?

Comment: You can't guarantee that, can you? It's possible for the casino to get unlucky and lose many games in a row once John comes in.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth So, there is no threshold, which we can compute. It's all about taking risk